# Checking if the 2nd list have any unique elements compared to 1st list

Tags: java, sorting, implementation, brute-force

Trying my own brute force solution. Now, there is a problem with my code I don't know what the problem is. I calculated the problem on my paper perfectly and it works great. It should work as expected. But gives unexpected results.

Problem: [Missing Number](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/missing-numbers/problem?isFullScreen=true)

**Code:**

```
public static List<Integer> getMissingNumber (List<Integer> arr, List<Integer> brr){

Integer[] value = new Integer[brr.size()]; 
value = brr.toArray(value); 

   for(int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
       for(int j=0; j<brr.size(); j++){
           if(arr.get(i)==brr.get(j)){
               value[j]=0;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
  Arrays.sort(value);
  List<Integer> exect_value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
       if(value[i]!=-1) {
           exect_value.add(value[i]);
       }
   }

return Arrays.asList(value);
}
```

Problem I'm Facing here:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
               for(int j=0; j<brr.size(); j++){
                   if(arr.get(i)==brr.get(j)){
                       value[j]=0;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
```

When I tested for:
Taking 2 different
**input(Function will pass 2 list):**

```
arr[6] : [7,2,5,3,5,3] 
brr[8] : [7,2,5,4,6,3,5,3]
```

**output:** `[4,6]` you have to print elements that is not founded in **list_1**

**It works perfectly for this test case**

But

When I try for:
**Input:**

```
arr[10] =[11 4 11 7 13 4 12 11 10 14]
brr[15] = [11 4 11 7 3 7 10 13 4 8 12 11 10 14 12]
```

Output gives: `[0, 0, 11, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 11, 10, 0, 12]` This but
I'm expecting -> `[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 10, 0, 12]` extra `[11,4,11]` comes on this array.

Why I'm so confused, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try for: Input:
>
> ```
> arr[10] =[11 4 11 7 13 4 12 11 10 14]
> brr[15] = [11 4 11 7 3 7 10 13 4 8 12 11 10 14 12]
> ```
>
> Output gives: `[0, 0, 11, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 11, 10, 0, 12]` This but I'm expecting -> `[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 10, 0, 12]` extra `[11,4,11]` comes on this array.

That is because here:

> ```
>    for(int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
>        for(int j=0; j<brr.size(); j++){
>            if(arr.get(i)==brr.get(j)){
>                value[j]=0;
>                break;
>            }
>        }
>    }
> ```

you are comparing `arr.get(i)` with `brr.get(j)` instead of `value[j]`.

---

PS. I seems that the proper solution is to sort and "anti-merge" two lists:

```java
    public static List<Integer> missingNumbers(List<Integer> arr, List<Integer> brr) {
        // Write your code here
        Collections.sort(arr);
        Collections.sort(brr);
        Set<Integer> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        int l = 0, r = 0;
        while (l < arr.size() && r < brr.size()) {
            if (arr.get(l).equals(brr.get(r))) {
                l++;
                r++;
            } else {
                result.add(brr.get(r++));
            }
        }
        for (; r < brr.size(); r++) {
            result.add(brr.get(r));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do some like that:

1. Change "==" for "equals()"
2. Set in brr array zero when some value has already been stored (because your problem was that you were comparing values ​​of arr that had already been validated). For example, you compared arr in position 2 against brr position 0 (Both values 11), then put 0 back where one already existed.

   ```
    Integer[] value = new Integer[brr.size()];
    value = brr.toArray(value); 
       for(int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
           for(int j=0; j<brr.size(); j++){
               if(arr.get(i).equals(brr.get(j))){
                   brr.set(j, 0);
                   value[j]=0;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

      Arrays.sort(value);
      List<Integer> exect_value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       for(int i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
           if(value[i]!=0) {
               exect_value.add(value[i]);
           }
       }

    return exect_value;
   ```